# watchOS only App – Privacy usage description in Info.plist

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect, watchos

I have developed an watchOS only app (app with complication for calendar and reminder access). After submitting it to the iTunes Connect I got the message

> Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code references one
> or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist
> file should contain a NSCalendarsUsageDescription key with a
> user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your
> app needs the data. ...

In my Info.plist of the WatchKit Extension there already exists these entries.

```
<key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
<string>Use for display calender timeline</string>
<key>NSRemindersUsageDescription</key>
<string>Use for display reminder timeline</string>
```

When I add these entries also in the WatchKit App Info.plist and upload the app to iTunes Connect I receive the following error while uploading.

> App Store Connect Operation Error ERROR ITMS-90363: "Invalid
> Info.plist key. The key 'NSCalendarsUsageDescription' in bundle
> xxx.app/Watch/xxx WatchKit App.app is invalid."
>
> App Store Connect Operation Error ERROR ITMS-90363: "Invalid
> Info.plist key. The key 'NSRemindersUsageDescription' in bundle
> xxx.app/Watch/xxx WatchKit App.app is invalid."

So how can I fix that problem and upload my WatchOS only app?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I tried to manually adding the entitlements to the archived file but then the submission complains about the entitlements again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in a WatchOS app using Bluetooth. Only that the error was about `NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription`.

My resolution was to only add the entries to the WatchKit Extension Info.plist and remove the entries from the WatchKit App Info.plist.

Comment: After doing this, I was able to upload but after processing I got an email telling me I needed to have `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription`, and that although not required, I should also add `NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription `

Comment: What actually worked for me are the steps provided by peteradstahl in this thread: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/125768